# Origami Ver 4.5.1-0 to 4.5.1-7 on windows 10, Couldn't load library library opencv_java451 exception while compiling

Tags: windows, opencv, origami

Following Getting Started at https://cljdoc.org/d/origami/origami/4.1.2-7/doc/readme#getting-started

#### install the sample

```
lein new clj-opencv hello-origami
```

#### change directory

```
cd hello-origami
```

#### run the template simple example

```
D:\Work\iprnd\clojure\hello-origami>lein run
```

Loading: opencv_java451

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, compiling:(opencv4/ok.clj:1:1)** at
> clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7526) at
> clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:379) at
> clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370) at
> clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:460) at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:426)
> at clojure.core$load$fn__6548.invoke(core.clj:6046).... .....at
> clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:702) at
> clojure.main.main(main.java:37) Caused by:
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348).... ... at
> clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7062) at
> clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7051) at
> clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7514) ... 40 more
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Couldn't load library library opencv_java451** at
> origami.Origami.init(Origami.java:121) at
> opencv4.core__init.load(Unknown Source) at opencv4.core__init.(Unknown
> Source) ... 71 more
>
> **Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't load library library opencv_java451** at
> org.scijava.nativelib.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:141)
> at origami.Origami.init(Origami.java:117) ... 73 more
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java451 in java.library.path** at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867) at
> java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) at
> java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) at
> org.scijava.nativelib.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:136)
> ... 74 more

Experiencing same problem from 4.5.1-0 to 4.5.1-7.

Any advise please?

Comment: since you never mention it: did you *install* the opencv libs ? if so, how, and which version ?

Comment: Lein downloaded as a part of dependencies before starting the compliation. Dependencies include 1) [origami "4.5.1-0"],  this auto resulted in installing [opencv/opencv "4.5.1-0"] 2) [opencv/opencv-native "4.5.1-0" :classifier "windows_64"]. I've tried with both including and excluding the 2nd (native) dependency.

Comment: Opened an issue with owner of origami repo. He kindly replied and acknowledged the issue.  https://github.com/hellonico/origami/issues/81